# dict_values object has no attribute index

Tags: python-3.x

Im trying to code a decryption to the atbash cipher, Im rearranging the string by using a dictionary and appending those rearranged values back to a list and returning it.

```
def atbash(txt):
ph = []
lst = []
atbashdict = {"a":"z","b":"y","c":"x","d":"w","e":"v","f":"u","g":"t",
"h":"s","i":"r","j":"q","k":"p","l":"o","m":"n","n":"m","o":"l","p":"k",
"q":"j","r":"i","s":"h","t":"g","u":"f","v":"e","w":"d","x":"c","y":"b",
"z":"a"}
if " " in txt:
    ph = txt.split()
    for i in range(len(ph)):
        for j in ph[i]:
            if j.lower() in atbashdict.keys():
                if j.isupper()==True:
                    lst[i].append(list(atbashdict.keys())[list(atbashdict.values().index(j.lower()))].upper())
                else:
                    lst[i].append(list(atbashdict.keys())[list(atbashdict.values().index(j))])
            if j.isalpha()==False:
                lst[i].append(j)            
    return(" ".join(lst))
for i in txt:
    if i.isupper()==True:
        if i.lower() in atbashdict.keys():
            lst.append(list(atbashdict.keys())[list(atbashdict.values().index(i.lower()))].upper())
    else:
        if i in atbashdict.keys():
            lst.append(list(atbashdict.keys())[list(atbashdict.values().index(i))])
return("".join(lst))
```

When I go to run the code with test "abcdefghijklmnop" I am greeted with this error:

```
ERROR: Traceback:
  in <module>
  in atbash
 AttributeError: 'dict_values' object has no attribute 'index'
```

I am confused after trying to remedy myself, I wrapped in list yet same error... Please help!

Answer (score 2):

The `.values()` methods on a dictionary does not return a `list`; rather, it returns a `dict_values`. To convert is to a `list` you have to do `list(dictionary.values()).index()`.